# Debian installation on MegaRaid SAS 9266-4i

Tags: debian, sas, megaraid

I have server here, with Intel Xeon CPU on Intel MB and with MegaRAID SAS 9266-4i. I need completely reinstall this server, however I'm not able to see this raid in Partition manager. Tried to load drivers in installer but probably in bad way. What is correct process to do this?

Debian version to install is 8.1.

Thank a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to install any OS on this server (including Ubuntu, CentOS, OpenSUSE and others), I sucessfully tried to install Proxmox, allowed me to create more independent environments. I use Proxmox`s NAT to forwarding requests to selected VPS.